# Valid email fails validation on add - but regex rule seems not the reason?

Tags: email

I want to add a somehow extraordinary email address to a civicrm contact:

`st.-georg-schule.heide@schule.landsh.de`

As it failed, I tested the rule in

`packages/HTML/QuickForm/Rule/Email.php`

and it matches, see:

https://regex101.com/r/0Tu5YQ/1

So I do not have a clue what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just recently fixed in 5.42 - see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2769